# V93k testmethodlimits section in .tf file is incorrect for SpecSearch

Tags: origen-sdk

After loading my test program I'm getting a 93k SmarTest inconsistency error for a SpecSearch Test Method.   Origen inserts a parameter labeled Functional in the testmethodlimits section of a .tf file when it should be SpecSearch_Test.  I add the correct parameter to my .tf file the inconsistency is resolved.

[SmarTest Inconsistency Check window with incorrect parameter identified.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqCse.jpg)

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Hi Jim, this seems to be a bug you are reporting rather than a question about Origen, is that correct?
If so, would you mind opening an issue over here instead, then we can ask you more questions about what is going on - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen/issues
Thanks!

Comment: Created issue #251 to Github Origen-SDK/origen